# Octave-mode disable octave-sync-function-file-names on save

Tags: octave

Is there a variable I can set to disable the call of `octave-sync-function-file-names` after saving a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such variable.  However, you can still do this, by removing the function from `before-save-hook`.  This is untested, but try:

```el
(remove-hook  'before-save-hook 'octave-sync-function-file-names t)
```

You'll have to do this in each octave-mode buffer, so you should probably do it from `octave-mode-hook` like this:

```el
(defun my-octave-deactivate-sync-function ()
  "Don't check equality of function and file names.
Add this to `octave-mode-hook'."
  (remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'octave-sync-function-file-names t))

(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook #'my-octave-deactivate-sync-function)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this piece! I accidentally found out that you can cheat around it by have a statement in the first line of the file. It can be anything like `0;` or `a=4;`

Comment: Removing the hook had no effect for me, but Daniel's kluge did.

Comment: @DanielHitzel Yes that works because the file is no longer a function file but an [octave script file](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Script-Files.html). This is detected by `octave-function-file-p`: "Return non-nil if the first token is \"function\"."

Comment: @holocronweaver I've added some code example that works for me.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
(defun octave-sync-function-file-names () (ignore))
```